# Call class to add two numbers in Java

Tags: java

I just started Java and have no idea how to call the class and use the correct variables. I have a Calculator.java file where I have methods to read 2 int , add them or multiply them. (paste them at the end)

Calculator.java

```
class Calculator {

    int x;
    int y;

    public setNumbers(int x, int y) {

        System.out.print("Input the first number: ");
        return x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the second number: ");
        return y = in.nextInt();

    }

    public addNumbers(){

        return x + y;

    }

    public multiplyNumbers(){

        return x * y;

    }
}
```

CalculatorApp.java

```
class CalculatorApp extends Calculator {

    public int pr() {
        return pr();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int choice;

        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following options: \n[1] - Set numbers \n[2] - Add Numbers \n[3] - Multiply numbers \nYour choice is: ");  
        choice = in.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

            case 1: setNumbers();
                break;

            case 2: addNumbers();
                break;

            case 3: multiplyNumbers();
                break;


        }

    }

}
```

Errors:

```
 .\Calculator.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        public setNumbers(int x, int y) {
               ^
.\Calculator.java:15: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        public addNumbers(){
               ^
.\Calculator.java:21: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        public multiplyNumbers(){
               ^
.\Calculator.java:9: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                return x = in.nextInt();
                         ^
.\Calculator.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                return x = in.nextInt();
                           ^
  symbol:   variable in
  location: class Calculator
.\Calculator.java:11: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                return y = in.nextInt();
                         ^
.\Calculator.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                return y = in.nextInt();
                           ^
  symbol:   variable in
  location: class Calculator
.\Calculator.java:17: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                return x + y;
                         ^
.\Calculator.java:23: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                return x * y;
                         ^
CalculatorApp.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                choice = in.nextInt();
                         ^
  symbol:   variable in
  location: class CalculatorApp
CalculatorApp.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                        case 1: setNumbers();
                                ^
  symbol:   method setNumbers()
  location: class CalculatorApp
CalculatorApp.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                        case 2: addNumbers();
                                ^
  symbol:   method addNumbers()
  location: class CalculatorApp
CalculatorApp.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                        case 3: multiplyNumbers();
                                ^
  symbol:   method multiplyNumbers()
  location: class CalculatorApp
13 errors
```

Comment: Between public and the function name put whatever you want to return (int, double, etc). Also use `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: Your methods have no return type give them a return type. In your case return Int.

Comment: truly speaking there is nothing correct in the code you need to clear your basics  just google it many tutorials are availble.

Comment: Ok. Codeacademy does not provide enough info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. If you want me to explain for some basic understanding, write comment below.

Calculator.java

```
public class Calculator {
    int x;
    int y;
    public void setNumbers(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int addNumbers(){
        return x + y;
    }

    public int multiplyNumbers(){
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

CalculatorApp.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalculatorApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the following options: \n[1] - Set numbers \n[2] - Add Numbers \n[3] - Multiply numbers \n[4] - Exit\nYour choice is: ");  
            choice = in.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:                    
                    System.out.print("\nInput the first number: ");
                    int x = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("\nInput the second number: ");
                    int y = in.nextInt();
                    calculator.setNumbers(x, y);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    int sum = calculator.addNumbers();
                    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int multiply = calculator.multiplyNumbers();
                    System.out.println("Multiply: " + multiply);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Compile **javac Calculator.java**, than **javac CalculatorApp.java**. And run **java CalculatorApp**

Comment: Thank you. Some basic questions:

Comment: -What does `this.x` do?
- Can I use `in.nextInt();` without `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` ?

Comment: @VictorMarcu this.x refers to the global variable in your class as you could see that the function setNumber(int x,int y) has a variable x and also x is globally defined under the same class ,here this keyword comes it .

Comment: @java-fan is right. Also you can not use `in.next()` alone, because you are trying to invoke method of an object, for which you need the reference of the object. That is why we first created the object of `Scanner` class. So `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` is required line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Every function in java requires a return type it is the value which a method returns if it returns an integer value then return type is int ,if a floting value then return type is float.

Also note that you have use in.nextInt();
that also is wrong you have to use scanner to take input.
Also setNumbers method takes two argument that is not needed as you take numbers from user inside the method only.
and i think tht the lines

```
public int pr() {
        return pr();
    }
```

make no sense.

Comment: Ok, modified it, but don't know how to use Scanner

Comment: Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  System.out.println("Enter x");  
   int x=sc.nextint();  System.out.println("Enter y");  
   int y=sc.nextint();

Comment: @VictorMarcu give me a minute or two i will post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I think in your Calculator class , your functions are missing return types where you are returning value from function.

Your calculator class could be like this.

```
class Calculator {

  int x;
  int y;

  public void setNumbers() {

    System.out.print("Input the first number: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input the second number: ");
    this.y = in.nextInt();

  }

  public int addNumbers(){

    return this.x + this.y;

  }

  public int multiplyNumbers(){

    return this.x * this.y;

  }
}
```

Also use "Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); " in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the complete code which might work

```
class Calculator {

    int x;
    int y;

    public void  setNumbers() {

        System.out.print("Input the first number: ");
        x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the second number: ");
       y = in.nextInt();

    }

    public int addNumbers(){

        return x + y;

    }

    public int  multiplyNumbers(){

        return x * y;

    }
}
```

and the class calculator app

```
 class CalculatorApp extends Calculator {

        public int pr() {
            return pr();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);        
    int choice;

            //note you have to setnumbers before you could add or multiply them
    System.out.println("Press 1 to add numbers");
    Syste.out.print("Press 2 to multiply numbers");

    choice = sc.nextInt();
               setNumbers();
            switch (choice) {

                case 1: 
                system.out.print(  addNumbers());
                    break;

                case 2:
System.out.print( multiplyNumbers());
                    break;

               default:
    S.op.ln("Invalid choice");

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Calculator {

    int x;
    int y;

    public void setNumbers() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Input the first number: ");
        this.x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the second number: ");
        this.y = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public int addNumbers(){

        return this.x + this.y;

    }

    public int multiplyNumbers(){

        return this.x * this.y;

    }
}

public class CalculatorApp{
 public int pr() {
        return pr();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator cal = new Calculator();
        int choice;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the following options: \n[1] - Add Numbers \n[2] - Multiply numbers \nYour choice is: ");  
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

            case 1: 
                cal.setNumbers();
                System.out.println(cal.addNumbers());
                break;

            case 2: 
                cal.setNumbers();
                System.out.println(cal.multiplyNumbers());
                break;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.